# How to sync a shared iCal with Outlook Calendar without iPhone (No iPhone, Mac (Catalina), Mail- Outlook, have icloud account)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar, calendar.app

I have an iCloud account and MAC (Catalina) but no iPhone. My boss has shared his iCal by sending me an invite on my Outlook email but I am not able to sync his iCal with my Outlook Calendar. Also, I dont have the access to share his iCal as he is the only owner. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you could sync your iCloud calendar with Outlook for Mac, for more information, please check this [official document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-your-icloud-calendar-with-outlook-for-mac-c9c67e41-274f-4527-ae5e-ea1003d89fc5).